# Server Side Routing vs. Front End Routing with Proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I hope my question doesn't come off as silly.  I have quite a bit of experience on the front end but very little on the back end.

I have a React application which uses Node.js and Express on the back-end.  I have declared `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` in my `package.json` which I am not 100% what this does but I know it is helping to connect my server (which runs on port 3001).

The issue I am having came about while setting up Auth0 on my backend to verify users. The first thing I noticed was that I was not able to run a get request to `http://localhost:3001/login` instead I had to navigate the user to the url `http://localhost:3001/login`.  I'm not sure why this is but I assume it has something to do with Auth0 settings.

After I login Auth0 returns users to a callback url.  Auth0's docs recommend using `localhost:3000/callback` since there docs also have a backend endpoint at `/callback`. However after logging in the user just gets routed to an empty page at `http://localhost:3000/callback` and the backend endpoint is never hit.  I found that strange since I was basically copying and pasting from the Auth0 guide to setting up a login with Express.

Anyway I found that if I changed the callback url to my server at `http://localhost:3001/callback` than the server side code runs.  This makes sense other than the Auth0 docs saying to use port 3000. It seems like maybe my proxy should be linking these somehow.

The callback endpoint function looks like this:

```
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('called')
    passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
            delete req.session.returnTo;
            res.redirect(returnTo || '/user');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

When this runs successfully it should route the user to my Users page at `localhost:3000/users` however because I changed the callback route to 'localhost:3001/callback`the callback endpoint is routing me to`localhost:3001/users`.

I can kind of see what is going on.  When I go to a url using 3001 I am hitting my endpoints.  When I go to a url using 3000 I am viewing my front end pages.  I just don't understand why the Auth0 docs would tell me to use my front end port for the callback?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help but I'm not sure this is the answer.

If you set in your package.json the proxy to `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` then in your app to make a request you don't need to use the full URL,

```
axios.get('/login').then(res=>res.data).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

For example without the proxy setted

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login').then(res=>res.data).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

In Auth0 the host URL and port is not a problem, U can use whatever U want, the point is the `/callback` route, in Auth0 you can configure a custom route for the callback but by default in your app, you need to have a route `/callback`. remember to add localhost:3001 to Auth0 configurations

I hope to help.